# Goto page with textfield value as hash

Tags: javascript, submit, form-submit, textfield

Ok, this should be easy but for me it doesn't seem so... probably because i'm very close to the deadline and have a lot to do.

This is what i'm trying to do;
I have an html form with a textfield and a button - whenever the button is clicked or enter is pressed i would like it to goto a particular page with the text field's value on the end as a hash.

for instance;
user enters "test" and presses enter or hits the button and the page goes to "google.com#test"

Answer (score 0):

```
<html>
<head>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    function do_it() {
      var hash = document.getElementById("hash_input").value;
      window.location = "http://google.com#"+hash;
    }
  </script>
</head>
<body>

<input id="hash_input" type="text"></input>
<input type="button" onclick="do_it()" value="Go"></input>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: umm adding the hash is pretty much the one thing i was sure of how to do... i need the hash on the end of a link to a different page. ie a dynamic link based on the text field

Comment: @John: Okay, not sure if I'm missing something because it doesn't seem much different, but I changed the example accordingly.